# ん in strange places: そんなんで

Tags: grammar, meaning, parsing

I am translating this from the manga Attack on Titan:

> そんなんでイザッて時に戦えんの

The show translates this text to:

> Can you fight like that if you have to?
> (the main character is asking a guy if he is able to fight drunk if they are suddenly attacked)

I am familiar with 「そんな」. The next part 「んで」I don't get. Then we flip to an unfamiliar combo of kana 「イザッて」. I get the time part. The last part is about war so that makes sense....except that 「ん」 slid his way in again.

Comment: You'll find in anime and manga the speech is all informal and slangy. ん、ざ、ぜ、だ、だろう and what-not are all commonplace.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> そんなんでイザッて時に戦えんの

would be a colloquial way of saying

> そんなので(≒そんな[風]{ふう}で/そんな状態で/そんな調子で)、いざという時に戦えるの？

Breakdown:

そんなの -- like that; something like that (そんな + particle の as a nominalizer)
[で](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/148951/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A7/) -- a case particle/格助詞  (そんなので here would be like "If you're (drunk) like that")
[いざという時](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E3%81%84%E3%81%96%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AB%22) -- in an emergency; in time of need ([いざ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/10904/meaning/m0u/) is an interjection/感嘆詞)
戦える -- the potential form of the verb 戦う
の -- a sentence ending particle/終助詞